# How to extract all words in a string with preg_match before a specific character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

Say we have the following string:

> Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3: Terminator4

And the given regex which only saves Terminator3

```
(\w+)(?=:)
```

How I must save the first 3 Terminators in a string, because the php's preg_match offers to save results only as array? I'm thinking to use `implode()` as the only option for gluing all words ...

Example result:

```
var_dump($terminators);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Terminator1"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Terminator2"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "Terminator3"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have more example strings which will run through the process? It would help refined answers on what will work out. Also, could you add some exact results you wish to see for each example?

Comment: All of them are the same - some text on the left and right, separated by : and space

Comment: Ok, but do you mean `Terminators` in code, or do you mean `anywordhere` literals, or Terminators that are coming to wipe us all out? :) (sorry couldn't resist) ... your edit is more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Any word, because words are different on every script run

Comment: Like https://ideone.com/9kL2nW?

Comment: Ok, this works and no Terminators near our base. But how exactly I can choose the end character if not : and space?

Comment: Try [`\G\s*\K\w+(?=(?:\s+\w+)*:)`](https://regex101.com/r/62EuTl/1). `(?=(?:\s+\w+)*:)` will assure there is a `:` after some space-separated words. If there can be any non-word chars between words, use [`\G\W*\K\w+(?=(?:\W+\w+)*:)`](https://regex101.com/r/62EuTl/2). Well, you may do all that in 2 steps: 1) grab all words before the `:` and then 2) `explode` if there are always spaces between them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow learn something new every day... I didn't even know that site existed, what a useful tool! I'd +10 that comment if I could.

Comment: So, is anything working as it should? The [2-step suggestion demo](https://ideone.com/Qpwpe0).

Comment: Yep, but do we need the \G ?

Comment: If you want to only match from the start of the string, yes. If there is no such a need, then no. Then [`\w+(?=(?:\s+\w+)*:)`](https://regex101.com/r/62EuTl/3) will do. See what happens when you do not define the exact requirements from the very beginning.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. Why is regex needed to return the part of a string before a specific character?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It is necessary when one wants to pre-validate what one extracts. Actually, the question is rather obscure.

Comment: @Don'tPanic One line solution instead of playing with strpos, array_search or explode. And is equally fast

Comment: @1000Gbps actually I was thinking of something more like the answer that was just added.

Comment: I saw it, already tested and impossible to catch for a given word, especially when the text is non Latin. For example some words are at Terminator2's position, some at [0], some near the :

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "catch for a given word"? Can you edit the question to show what output you're actually trying to get? It seems you may need a more illustrative example.

Comment: Don't think it will enlighten the problem more. If I use strtok (explode is faster) or something similar, I should remove the colon, then split the string into an array, then loop the array and match each element to specific needle, and then continue with program's logic. Think preg is faster, but probably someone can provide a faster substr solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I'd use regex for this task (unless you have a special requirement) because there are faster single-function non-regex methods available.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a42ce82690e39f980a5af844bff77d655d118f3))

```
$input='Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3: Terminator4';
//$input='Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3 Terminator4'; // no delimiter

echo "strstr: ";
var_export(strstr($input,':',true));  // false when no delimiter is found
echo "\n\n";

echo "strtok: ";
var_export(strtok($input,':'));  // fullstring when no delimiter is found
echo "\n\n";

echo "explode: ";
var_export(explode(':',$input,2)[0]);  // fullstring when no delimiter is found
echo "\n\n";

echo "preg_replace: ";
var_export(preg_replace('/:.*/','',$input));  // fullstring when no delimiter is found
echo "\n\n";

echo "preg_match: ";
var_export(preg_match('/[^:]*/',$input,$out)?$out[0]:'error');  // fullstring when no delimiter is found
echo "\n\n";

echo "preg_split: ";
var_export(preg_split('/:.*/',$input)[0]);  // fullstring when no delimiter is found
```

Output:

```
strstr: 'Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3'

strtok: 'Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3'

explode: 'Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3'

preg_replace: 'Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3'

preg_match: 'Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3'

preg_split: 'Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Terminator1 Terminator2 Terminator3: Terminator4";

$result = strtok($string, ":");

echo $result;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for sharing. Can you add a bit more context why this solves the problem, please?

Comment: php strtok() split string one by one, in this case we use the ":" to be the basis on where to split the string.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in 2 steps,

1. Match `[^:]+(?=:)`
2. Explode the result on whitespace.

All done!